# SpaceX Avionics

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, falcon-heavy, dragon, avionics

Just wondering what are some avionics aboard the falcon 9 and heavy. also what are some avionics on the dragon? Just general avionics that play a pivotal role in space travel.

Comment: I see this is your very first time to SE. There many rules and stuff you should read up on to get a good answer. +1 because you came to Space.SE first.